# Do you have to follow the itinerary submitted during the US visa application?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

A first timer friend registered say Houston on his application, and later decides to come into the US through New York. He hears that he must compulsorily land in Houston and nowhere else, since that's the city that was registered on the application, without which he'll have problems with the Immigrations in New York (or any other city apart from Houston) and might be sent back.

Is this true?

Comment: What is the country of origin and your friend's citizenship?  Is it a multi-entry visa?  Who told him he *must* land in Houston?

Comment: He's Nigerian and traveling from Nigeria. Yes it is a multi-entry visa. A resident of the US and some friends told him he must land in Houston.

Comment: I read it on the Internet, it must be true.

Comment: This doesn't sound true. And note that a couple months ago it was completely impossible to land in Houston airport due to hurricane.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such regulation. Visa for the US are *for the US*, not for Houston or Cornfield, Iowa, or whatever.

Many countries don’t even have direct flights to Houston, so even if you book a connection, you will land somewhere else, go through immigration, and then take a domestic connection (where there is no immigration, and nobody cares about visa status).

Note though that the visa is not an automatic entry; the visa holder will still be questioned by immigration officers, and if they think something is conspicuous, they can deny entry. It is important to be able to *present a clear and convincing planning of what you plan to do, how you can afford it, and when you will leave*. But it doesn’t matter what the original planned city was.